# Twitter 4j Query and Filtered Query

Tags: java, twitter4j

I'm searching some specific list of keywords from Twitter.

The following code snippets are working:

```
FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
fq.track("keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3", "keyword4");
twitterStream.filter(fq);
```

But i need to put since and until functions to make a search for specific time interval. To do this i have to define my query like ;

```
Query query = new Query("(keyword1) OR (keyword2) OR (keyword3) OR (keyword4)");
query.setSince("20110101");
query.setUntil("20160210");
```

How can i change my `FilteredQuery` to `Query` instance to have access to add since and until methods.

Moreover i have to make same for the statement of `twitterStream.filter(fq);`

Because this statement does not accept query as an input parameter, like (`twitterStream.filter(query)`)

Thank you very much for your interests..

Answer (score 0):

After making some search among this issue i found that with using FilteredQuery i can just use keyword for listening new tweets. And also by using Query with date interval i can only get tweets for 7-10 days ago. Moreover Twitter Company gives an access to Gnip Software which sells 1 million tweets over a 40 day period and start at $1,250.